# Can't fire script with CFThread, CFExecute and Plink

Tags: batch-file, coldfusion, plink, cfthread, cfexecute

I am needing to run a remote script on our network to import files.  I have set up plink and have it working as needed if I run it manually.

> plink name@localserver -ssh -i myKey.ppk /home/here/scriptName.sh

We are writing the code in ColdFusion so this will run in a CFThread using CFExecute.
The cfexecute does not error when I run it via the code it just not fire the script.

In my research I have found people saying that cfexecute has some issues with the argument string and a better idea is creating a batch file and using cfexecute to run the batch file.

so I have created a batch file.
    import.bat

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\plink\plink.exe name@localserver -ssh -i myKey.ppk /home/here/scriptName.sh)
```

again if I run the the batch file manually it works.

> import.bat

but if I run it via cfexecute it does nothing.

To test cfexecute I have it running two commands, the first what I need to work and the second a test.  the second works as needed.  the first one is not erroring to screen or log file.  It did if I entered bad syntax.  The second is writing to file as needed.

(code below)

```
                starting

                <cfoutput>

                <cfexecute name = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\plink\import.bat"   errorfile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\logs\#timeformat( now(),"HHMMSS") #.log"  ></cfexecute>

                <cfexecute name = "C:\WinNT\System32\netstat.exe"
                            arguments = "-e" 
                            outputFile = "C:\Temp\#timeformat( now(),"HHMMSS") #.txt"
                            timeout = "1">
                    </cfexecute>



                </cfoutput>
                the end
            <cfabort>
```

any thoughts would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Have you tried running either the plink command or the batch file while logged in as the user the ColdFusion service runs as? Sounds like a permission issue.

Comment: You may also want to run 'cmd c:\path\to\batchfile.bat args' as I'm not sure that cfexecute will execute a batch file like that. I think you need to run the command interpreter and tell that to run a batch file.

Comment: Use errorVariable="foo" to return the error to a variable and then output foo.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<cfexecute name="c:\winNt\system32\cmd.exe"
 arguments="/c C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\plink\import.bat" timeout="100">
</cfexecute>
```

Comment: Please add clarification as to why this will help.

Comment: @Zane As far as I know this is the correct way to execute batch files in cfexecute. But there may be other ways with which I am not familiar.

Comment: The criticism has nothing to do with the code in question. I has to do with the lack of explanation which is why another user has flagged your question as low quality.

Comment: In my opinion the question is obvious and so is the possible answer. I try to avoid unnecessary comments and explanations. However your comment is noted and appreciated.